# IBM DB2: Run SQL Scripts

Tags: variables, global, ibm-midrange, navigator

Using the iSeries Navigator, the "Run SQL Scripts" utility.

Is it possible to use a global variable to do the following:

1. Create or Replace Variable FileName Char(21) Default 'V51BPCSF00.ESN'
2. Select * From FileName

Thanks

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish, especially with the select statement?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, compound statements are supported (since 2014 in v7r1+ )so you might think to try something like so..

```
--create variable
Create or Replace Variable FileName Char(21) Default 'CWILT/MYTABLE';
```

then the compound statement

```
begin
  declare myStmt varchar(500);
  
  set myStmt = 'Select * from ' concat filename;
  
  prepare s1 from myStmt;
  execute s1;
end;
```

But that didn't work for me.

However, behind the scenes the DB is simply creating a stored procedure with your compound statement.   You can simply do it yourself.

```
create or replace procedure cwilt5.test
language SQL
dynamic result sets 1
begin
  declare myStmt varchar(500);
  declare c1 cursor with return to client for s1 ;
  
  set myStmt = 'Select * from ' concat filename;
  
  prepare s1 from myStmt;
  open c1;
end;
```

While the above uses the global variable as requested, I'd probably just pass in the file name as a parameter.

Key thing to realize is that variables aren't supported in the `FROM` clause of a static SQL statement.  You have to use dynamic SQL, `PREPARE` & `EXECUTE` or `OPEN` if you need to return a result set.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create or Replace Variable FileName Char(21) Default 'V51BPCSF00.ESN'
2. SELECT FileName from sysibm.sysdummy1

sysibm.sysdummy1 is a "fake" file to allow this type of select that needs a complete SQL statement.

I specify a library for the variable so I know where it is, and delete it afterwards if it's serving as a temporary variable

Create or Replace Variable MY_LIB.FileName Char(21) Default 'V51BPCSF00.ESN'

Do stuff .....

DROP Variable MY_LIB.FileName

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).